# Is there any to let RecycleView's first visible item get focus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

There is some code snippet in my project which used `RecycleView`.

Is there any way to let the first visible item to get the focus rather than the last visible item?

```
// The picture marked with RED
parentRecycleView.setAdapter(ParentAdapter)
```

```
// The picture marked with GREEN
parentRecycleViewViewHolder.populate(xxxx){
   childRecycleView.setAdapter(ChildAdapter)
}
```

Then I scroll to the first item.

```
parentRecycle.scrollToPosition(0)
```

As you can see in the capture below: the last visible  one got the focus(EditText) auto.

**My Question is:**
Is there any to let the first visible item to get  focus(EditText)?

[The image capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp6oc.png)

Answer (score 0):

To get the first visible item
First  visible child depends on the `LayoutManager`. If you are using `LinearLayoutManager` or `GridLayoutManager`, you can use

```
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();   
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

For example:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = ((GridLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

For LinearLayoutManager, first/last depends on the adapter ordering. Don't query children from RecyclerView; LayoutManager may prefer to layout more items than visible for caching.

Now once you have the visible item you can send the focus using requestfocus() function.

And that's it.

Hope it helps.

Thank you!